# What is this MIPS array + loop doing?

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips, mips32

New to MIPS and can understand exactly what is going on with the code, but I do not understand the answer/solution provided. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. Please read the following code and write down the content in array A after funct returns.

   ```
       .data
   A:  .word 21,3,2,9,100,22,6,15,33,90

       .text
       .globl main
   main:
       la $a0, A
       li $a1, 17
       li $a2, 10
       jal funct

       li $v0, 10      # exit
       syscall

   funct:
       li $t0, 0
       li $v1, 1000000
   funct_L0:   
       sll $t1, $t0, 2
       add $t1, $t1, $a0
       lw $t1, 0($t1)  
       sub $t2, $t1, $a1
       bgt $t2, $0, funct_L1
       sub $t2, $0, $t2
   funct_L1:
       bgt $t2, $v1, funct_L2
       ori $v0, $t0, 0
       ori $v1, $t2, 0
   funct_L2:
       addi $t0, $t0, 1
       blt $t0, $a2, funct_L0
       jr $ra
   ```

SOLUTION: Finds the smallest difference

Comment: In order to get text formatted as code, indent it 4 spaces and make sure it's preceded and followed by blank lines.  For future reference.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It finds the element from the array which is nearest to the number passed in in `$a1`. In other words, it finds the element `x` for which the difference `abs(x - $a1)` is smallest. It returns the index in `$v0` and the difference in `$v1`.